Is there a way to read from an actively written log file without blocking in .NET?
I have some C# code that is trying to consume lines from a file as that file is being appended to. The file gets rotated periodically, so it is important that I be able to "give up" rather than hanging if a file won't be updated any more.
My code roughly looks like this:
while (true)
{
    var path = LocateFile(); // scans the expected location for new files
    using StreamReader reader = new(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    StringBuilder line = new();
    DateTime noCharsFoundSince = DateTime.UtcNow;
    while (true)
    {
        var readResult = reader.Read();
        if (readResult >= 0)
        {
            noCharsFoundSince = null;
            var @char = (char)readResult;
            if (@char == '\n')
            {
                ProcessLine(line.ToString());
                line.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                line.Append(@char);
            }
        }
        else
        {
             if (DateTime.UtcNow - noCharsFoundSince.Value > MaxIdleTime) { break; }
             Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

This code works nearly perfectly, but very occasionally it seems to hang. I'm wondering if StreamReader.Read() can block indefinitely in some scenarios? If so, is there a way to guarantee that Read() won't hang, such as checking stream.Length > stream.Position before reading?
I'm running .NET 8 on Linux.

May be use StreamReader.ReadAsync(..., cancellationToken) with cancellation? If reading exceeds tolerable timeout we cancel it?

"The file gets rotated periodically" - what does it means? A new file is created? Then you can monitor for new file and stop (interrupt) current reading.

What is readRead?

StreamReader.Read may return 0!

@StriplingWarrior: Must be a typo for readResult.

@Sinatr what I mean is that the application stops appending to e.g. out_{timestamp1}.txt and starts appending to out_{timestamp2}.txt instead. My goal is to be able to finish consuming one file and move on to the next.

@StriplingWarrior I think the code handles the zero case, no? My issue is that when I expect zero sometimes I get hang instead.

I think you meant to reference @shingo with that question.

@ChaseMedallion your condition is readResult > 0, the zero case will cause the loop to sleep for 1s.

@shingo yes but then it can use the noCharsFoundSince case to break out right?

@ChaseMedallion, for your original code, if the input is like \0a\0a..., the loop will seem to be dead.

@shingo you're right; the version pasted here was checking for > 0 instead of >= 0, which I've now fixed. Unfortunately, that was a "reformat for stack-overflow" error; I checked the original code and it correctly treats anything >= 0 as a character (since Read() returns -1 on EOF).
